# Bootstrap Form Helper - remove unwanted countries from country picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-form-helper

Hi I'm using the bootstrap form helper country picker. But I need to display only set of chosen countries instead of all set. This is my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Form Helpers Basic Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Bootstrap Form Helpers -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-countryList="US,AG,AU" data-flags="true">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Form Helpers -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://js.nicdn.de/bootstrap/formhelpers/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-formhelpers-countries.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It would be great if someone knows a way to do it. But unfortunately it gives an empty drop down.

And I understand we can do it like,

```
<select class="form-control bfh-countries" data-available="US,AG,AU"></select>
```

But this way appears to be **without country flags**.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work you should add links to CSS and JS files of Bootstrap Form Helpers library which should be previously downloaded on your server.
[Bootstrap description](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/gettingstarted/#jquery-plugins)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer bro. I did it and learns that it's possible to filter countries but for me I need a filtered set with country flags. Unfortunately it seems impossible. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Ok. happy to help.